# Linux network device driver register for blueooth

Tags: linux-device-driver

As I known, The **register_netdevice()** was used to register an new network device. such eth0

How about bluetooth? Have any function to add new BT interface (eg. hci0)

thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1):

**hci_register_dev()** is used to register an hci(blutetooth) device.

see **net/bluetooth/hci_core.c**